# Series expansion at infinity not giving expected result

Tags: series-expansion

I have the function:

```
F = (4 + 2 x + x^2 - exp(x) (4 - 2 x + x^2))/(2(-1 + exp(x)) x^2)
```

I want to find the series of `F` at `x = Infinity`. I have tried `Series`

```
Series[F, {x, Infinity, 5}]
```

but it is giving something else like

> `(ⅇ^x(-1/2+1/x-2/x^2 +(O[1/x])^7)+(1/2+1/x+2/x^2 +(O[1/x])^7))/(-1+ⅇ^x)`

which is incorrect, It should be

> `-1/2 + 1/LPe - 2/LPe^2`

and so on.

Also when I tried the same in other software like Maple, I get the right answer, but not in Mathematica. Obviously, I can use the other software. But the problem with the other software, like Maple or Mupad, is the they can't handle multi-variate series, whereas Mathematica does. Therefore. my concern is with Mathematica.

Comment: Does it work if you correct `exp(x)` to `Exp[x]`?

Comment: You **can't** find the series at $\infty$ because $e^x$ has an **essential** singularity at $\infty$!!

Answer (score 3):

You can't find the series at $\infty$ because $e^x$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$!! Mathematica refuses to do it. For example the code

```
Series[Exp[x], {x, Infinity, 9}]
```

returns `Exp[x]` to indicate that Mathematica did not produce a series which doesn't exist.

EDIT: This happened with previous versions
of Mathematica, but currently it returns something slightly different which is still
not helpful because of the essential
singularity. What does work in all versions is

```
f = (4 + 2 x + x^2 - Exp[x] (4 - 2 x + x^2))/(2 (-1 + Exp[x]) x^2);
f // FullSimplify // InputForm
(* -1/2 - 2/x^2 + Coth[x/2]/x *)
```

This is better, but there still is **no** power series in $x$
because of the essential singularity.

Comment: It does not no longer.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I meant Series[Exp[x], {x, Infinity, 9}] == Exp[x] is not true.

Answer (score 2):

```
F = (4 + 2 x + x^2 - Exp[x] (4 - 2 x + x^2))/(2 (-1 + Exp[x]) x^2);

Normal[Series[F, {x, Infinity, 5}]] // FullSimplify
```

> -1/2 - 2/x^2 + Coth[x/2]/x

looks ok to me.

Comment: Maple produces $$ -1/2+{x}^{-1}-2\,{x}^{-2}+2\,{\frac {1}{x{{\rm e}^{x}}}}+O \left( {
\frac {1}{x \left( {{\rm e}^{x}} \right) ^{2}}} \right)
.$$

Comment: Yeah that looks a bit cleaner than the Mathematica result.

Comment: I have mention other coefficient below please look once at that also.